# Equation line exceeds width of text block

Tags: equations

I have a problem with an equation which almost exceeds limits of the page. This is the code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,blue,rgb,]{tubsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\mlbf[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
X[k1+4.k2]=\sum_{n2=0}^{N/4-1}[(x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]+(-1)^{k1}x[N  /2+n2]+(i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2])W_{N}^{k1.n2}]W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
\end{equation}
\label{eqfft4}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and i get this result :

[image]

how can i fix that???

Comment: broken it into more lines? is this possible option?

Comment: What is the tubsbook class?

Comment: Well for me it's possible and this is what i want to do if possible

Comment: Template of TU Braunschweig - Germany university

Comment: fix? what do you want to fix? do you want to make the text smaller? be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an issue of LaTeX formatting. If a formula is longer than the text width, it is hard to read and understand even if optimally typeset. I suggest to break down the formular by introducing abbreviations, e.g. in the following way. After that you can still decide to use some appropriate `amsmath` environment to align the equations.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
X[k1+4.k2]=\sum_{n2=0}^{N/4-1} \alpha(n2)\cdot W_{N}^{k1.n2}\cdot W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
\label{eqfft4}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\alpha(n2)= x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]+(-1)^{k1}x[N  /2+n2]+(i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use either a `multline` environment or a nested `equation`/`split` environment. At least one line break is required. Select the method that better fits your aesthetic sensibilities.

I further suggest you increase the sizes of the "outer" square brackets and round parentheses slightly to help the eye with determining where the main grouping is taking place.

Incidentally, what are the various `.` ("dot") characters supposed to signify? Are they multiplication "dots"? If so, they should be replace with `\cdot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro; automatically loads 'amsmath'
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
X[k1+4.k2]=\sum_{n2=0}^{\mathclap{N/4-1}}\bigl[\bigl( 
&x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]+(-1)^{k1}x[N/2+n2]\\
&+(i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2]\bigr) W_{N}^{k1.n2}\,\bigr] W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
X[k1+4.k2]=\sum_{n2=0}^{\mathclap{N/4-1}} 
\bigl[\bigl (x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]+(-1)^{k1}x[N/2+n2]\\
+(i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2]\bigr) W_{N}^{k1.n2}\,\bigr] W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
\end{multline}\label{eqfft4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Used `article` as document class, although this will work with any of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref} % MUST be last in preamble

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqfft4}
    \begin{multlined}[][0.8\linewidth]
X[k1+4.k2] = \sum_{n2=0}^{N/4-1}[(x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]  \\
                + (-1)^{k1}x[N/2+n2] 
                + (i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2])W_{N}^{k1.n2}]W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
    \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eqfft4}
    \begin{split}
X[k1+4.k2] 
    & = \sum_{n2=0}^{N/4-1}[(x[n2]+(-i)^{k1}x[N/4+n2]   \\
    &\qquad + (-1)^{k1}x[N/2+n2]                        \\
    &\qquad + (i)^{k1}x[3N/4+n2])W_{N}^{k1.n2}]W_{N/4}^{k2.n2}
    \end{split}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In your MWE, I removed all packages which are not relevant. Also I moved the `hyperref` package to the end of the preamble where it belongs. For the math environment `aligned` that was used I added the package `mathtools`, which provides an improved set of `amsmath` environments for writing multiline equations.

**Addendum:**
For completness I added one more possibiliy, which is how to split equation into more lines. I have no clue at which point you would like to break the equation, so I only showed one way of doing this and don't have any intention to decide it.

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you but it's not the good answer because even when it's split the equation balanced and the view is not good at all !

Comment: The answer is in frame of good math typing ... however, you not gives any information about your expectation about equation looks. So your complain i fill as insulting.